# run.sh not running with process builder

Tags: java, bash, shell

I have the following java code that should run my run.sh script.

```
public void executeScript() {
    try {
        Process p = null;
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("phoneManagement/src/run.sh");
        //pb.directory(new File("phoneManagement/src"));

        p = pb.start();     // Start the process.
        p.waitFor();               // Wait for the process to finish.
        System.out.println("Script executed successfully");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And the run.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
javac -cp ".:../../selenium/selenium-java-2.53.1.jar:../../selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar:../../selenium/libs/*" phoneManagement.java
java -cp ".:../../selenium/selenium-java-2.53.1.jar:../../selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar:../../selenium/libs/*" phoneManagement
```

If I run the .sh script from the command line it does what it should and my phoneManagement is compiled and executed.

When I use my executeScript class I get the message "Script executed successfully" although run.sh didn't do what it should.

can anyone help me with this ?

Thanx

Comment: Try using a full path. It's likely the command is failing, but i don't think it will give an exception. Try outputting the output from the command.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

`Process builder pb = new ProcessBuilder ("bash", "-c", "/path/to/shell/script/run.sh");`

Answer (score 0):

You must either specify full path to script `"/foo/bar/script.sh"` or use relative path with dot at the beginning `"./script.sh"`. Also don't forget to `chmod +x script.sh` and add proper shebang `#!/usr/bin/env bash` at the beginning of the script.